# reopen infowindow after it's closed in Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with streetview panorama, an infowindow and a draggable marker. After the marker is dragged, a function requests the getPanoramaByLocation to see whether the view service is available. If it's not, it closes the infowindow. That is great but when I click again on the marker the infowindow does not open anymore. Do you know what is wrong please?
tx

```
    var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

    function initialize() {

        var optionMap = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.390251,0.68882),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), optionMap);
        var optionsMarker = {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.390251,0.68882),
            map: myMap,
            draggable: true,
            title: "my marker"
            }
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(optionsMarker);
        var infowindowDiv = '<div id="streetview" style="width:300px;height:200px;"' +'</div>';

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infowindowDiv,
            position: myMap.getCenter() });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         infoWindow.open(myMap, marker);
         });

        google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
            var panorama = new
        google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("streetview"));
            panorama.setPosition(infoWindow.getPosition());

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
          sv.getPanoramaByLocation(event.latLng, 50, processSVData);});             

        function processSVData(data, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {

              var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
              // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID
              panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
              panorama.setPov({
                heading: 270,
                pitch: 0,
                zoom: 1
              });
              panorama.setVisible(true);
            } 
            else {
            infoWindow.close();
            infoWindow = null;              
            };
        }                   
    }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the GMaps API docs:

```
close() None    Closes this InfoWindow by removing it from the DOM structure.
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

So... If you close the infowindow, it's gone. For ever. All the more so if you REALLY make sure it's gone by saying "infoWindow = null;" You have to make a new one. My advice would be to refactor your code to have a separate function that creates the infowindow on demand and returns it. In your click event definition, check whether infowindow is null, and if so, grab a new one.

HTH

Comment: thanks you dda. I've tryed to create on demand infowindow but it does not work, by checking if (!infoWindow) and if(infoWindow) and many else but I can not do it.

Comment: SInce you set infowindow=null, use that as a test. First, put the variable outside the function; make it global so that it becomes a permanent reference. Then you will be able to test for infowindow==null, and decide accordingly whether to (re)create it.

Comment: I wrote a Google Maps Helper that makes my life easier when dealing with GM. Although it's far from complete, it could help you in this case keep keeping track for you of the markers and infoWindows. I'll put it up on GCode.

Comment: :-) merci; ça doit être super HK !

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer explain, the infobox html is removed from DOM when the user clicks the close button, but the JS object still there.

When you create an infowindow you must call the open method to see it on the map

```
myInfoWindow.open(mymap);
```

So, if you listen to the 'closeclick' event and keep the infowindow state

```
var infoWindowClosed = false;
google.maps.event.addListener(myInfoBox, "closeclick", function () {
    infoWindowClosed = true;
});
```

you can reopen myInfoWindow on demand

```
if(infoWindowClosed){
    myInfoWindow.open(mymap);
}
```